# Find supremum and infimum of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Check my answer.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Given $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$. $$S=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid x=\dfrac{1}{n}+(1+(-1)^n)n^2, n\in\mathbb{N}\right\}$$
Find $\sup S$ and $\inf S$.

I have tried to answer as below.
$$
x=
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{n}&\text{ if }n \text{ odd }\\
\dfrac{1}{n}+2n^2&\text{ if }n \text{ even}
\end{cases}
$$
The lower bound of $S$ is $0$ and no upper bound of $S$. So I can conclude
$$\sup S=\text{undefined}$$ and $$\inf S=0.$$

Does my answer is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct but one usaally writes $sup S=+\infty$ instead of saying that the supremum is not defined.